# Sorting of a list by an element inside the object by alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort the list by "Status" such that objects with "status" : "NOT_FOUND" appears first then the "status" : "OK" . That is in Alphabetical order

```
         let elements = [
{
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1.6 km",
                  "value" : 1550
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 mins",
                  "value" : 358
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
            }
         ];

                      //sort the elements 
                      elements.sort(function(a, b) {
                        if (typeof a.status !== 'undefined' && typeof b.status !== 'undefined') {
                          return  b.status - a.status 
                        }
                        return 0
                      });
                      console.log(elements);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-` is for numbers. Use localeCompare instead.

```
b.status.localeCompare(a.status);
```

Comment: I have another small question, I will have different values of status and what if I wanted to sort and also have an exception that if Status is 'OK' , have it always at the end?

Comment: You can write a condition `if(a.status=="OK") return -1;`. (You need to change the values maybe)